# PyQT4 Phonon players works but when compiled gives a wierd error

Tags: python, pyqt4, py2exe, phonon

im in need of help right now. i have been jumping sites and looking for a solution about this.
i Have this simple video player in pyQT4, i used phonon video player
if i run it through the .py extension. it works fine
(Note: i need to change my 4.7 QT4 to 4.8 QT4 for this to work. or else it will just hang on)

but after i compile it using py2exe and tried to run it, it gives me these error

```
WARNING: bool __thiscall Phonon::FactoryPrivate::createBackend(void) phonon back
end plugin could not be loaded

WARNING: bool __thiscall Phonon::FactoryPrivate::createBackend(void) phonon back
end plugin could not be loaded

WARNING: Phonon::createPath: Cannot connect  Phonon::MediaObject ( no objectName
 ) to  Phonon::VideoWidget ( no objectName ).

WARNING: bool __thiscall Phonon::FactoryPrivate::createBackend(void) phonon back
end plugin could not be loaded

WARNING: bool __thiscall Phonon::FactoryPrivate::createBackend(void) phonon back
end plugin could not be loaded

WARNING: bool __thiscall Phonon::FactoryPrivate::createBackend(void) phonon back
end plugin could not be loaded

WARNING: bool __thiscall Phonon::FactoryPrivate::createBackend(void) phonon back
end plugin could not be loaded

WARNING: Phonon::createPath: Cannot connect  Phonon::MediaObject ( no objectName
 ) to  Phonon::AudioOutput ( no objectName ).

WARNING: bool __thiscall Phonon::FactoryPrivate::createBackend(void) phonon back
end plugin could not be loaded

WARNING: bool __thiscall Phonon::FactoryPrivate::createBackend(void) phonon back
end plugin could not be loaded

WARNING: bool __thiscall Phonon::FactoryPrivate::createBackend(void) phonon back
end plugin could not be loaded
```

---

and here's the list of files inside the "dist" folder after compiling with

```
"setup.py py2exe"

phononsamp.exe

w9xpopen

phonon4.dll

phononwidgets.dll

python26.dll

qgif4.dll

qico4.dll

qjpeg4.dll

qmng4.dll

qsvg4.dll

QtCore4.dll

qtga4.dll

QtGui4.dll

qtiff4.dll

QtOpenGL4.dll
bz2.pyd

phonon.pyd

PyQt4.phonon.pyd

PyQt4.QtCore.pyd

PyQt4.QtGui.pyd

QtOpenGL.pyd

select.pyd

sip.pyd

unicodedata.pyd

library.zip
```

---

I really need someone to lighten up my minds, this is the first time i encountered this problem.

Comment: What files do you have in %QTDIR%\plugins\phonon_backend ?

Comment: Take a look at [py2exe with PyQt](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeAndPyQt), at the end of page.

Comment: Hi reclosedev, thanks for the help, thats what i needed on my setup file. thanks again, saves me a headache!